# Function inside of delegate event not triggered

Tags: objective-c, delegates, avaudioplayer

I have added this delegate to my implementation file, for some reason I cant change the image of the button but, I can see the log in the console.

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [PlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"] forState:0];
    NSLog (@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:");
}
```

It is weird because I'm able to change the button image anywhere else, and I  I can see the log in the console when the event is fired.

```
:-S
```

Here is how I assigned the delegate

```
avPlayer.delegate = self;
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
```

and here is how I set the playbutton outlet

```
@interface OneStepRecordViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
........
    IBOutlet UIButton *PlayButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *StopButton;
.......
}
```

Comment: How is PlayButton set and how is this delegate assigned?

Comment: @Chuck I just updated my post with more info

Comment: Have you confirmed whether playbutton.png is bundled into your app and can be successfully loaded outside of this code?

Comment: Is the log audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully: being shown in the console? Could you try to call the method setImage in main thread?

Comment: @esker yes Because thats how I set it, then I change to stopButton then ack to play once finish playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not have enough reputation to put comment

Please check if you have set the correct UIControlState,

In your code, your PlayButton may be in different state, i.e. not in UIControlStateNormal

Use

```
[PlayButton state];
```

to check the state.

You can place the check here

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"Play button state: %d", [PlayButton state]); // this line
    [PlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog (@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:");
}
```

Also for better understanding (programming practices), use this

```
[PlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of a "0" magic number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this helped solving my issues